# Angular 7 How to bring token and visit other pages after login? - JWT authentication example

Tags: angular

I would like to log in pages with `token` from a backend server written in Django (JWT token), I finally got a 200 in `login router` according this [angular-7-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/16/angular-7-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial), but after login, I don't know how to bring this token and visit other pages, add `currentUser` to recognize or import some files? Really stuck in this issue.
Any advices will be highly appreciated.

Partial code of `src/services/auth.service.ts` as below:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Auth, User } from '../domain';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<Auth>;
    public currentUser: Observable<Auth>;

    constructor(
      private http: HttpClient,
      @Inject('BASE_CONFIG') private config: { uri: string }
    ) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Auth>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}'));
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): Auth {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

    login(email: string, password: string): Observable<Auth> {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${this.config.uri}/users`, { email, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }
```

partial code of `src/services/project.service.ts` as below:

```
  // GET /projects
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ProjectService {
  private readonly domain = 'projects';
  private headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', '`Beader ${jwt}`');

  get(username: string): Observable<Project[]> {
    const uri = `${this.config.uri}/projects`;
    // const uri = `${this.config.uri}/project/`;
    const params = new HttpParams().set('members_like', username);
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(uri, {
      params: params,
      headers: this.headers
    });
  }
```

partial code of `src/helper/jwt.interceptor.ts` as below:

```
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
// import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        let currentUser = this.authService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service that make the request, you need to set the `Authorization` header to the value `Bearer <your_token>`

This is the standard way to authenticate in JWT.You server will then verify this token ( Signature, Audience, Date expiration ... ), and if valid, will pick the user identity in the payload.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
const options = {};
headers.set("Authorization", `Beader ${jwt}`";
options = { headers };

http.get<T>(path, body, options);
```

Where `http` refers to `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`

Basically you should follow this flow :

1. Exchange a token with user credential
2. Store the user token in the SessionStorage or as Cookie. I prefer SessionStorage as user may have block cookie.
3. In each service that need to send a HTTP request, retrieve this token and send it as Authorization header

To logout the user :

1. Send a request to the backend with the token to the logout endpoint.
2. Remove the token from SessionStorage/Cookie

Comment: Hi @Scandinave , I have a `jwt.interceptor.ts` file, and I updated the question with the whole code, could you please show me how to quote the header of `jwt.interceptor.ts`? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, I have a `jwt.interceptor.ts` file, could you please show me how to quote the header to make the request in `project.service.ts` ? Thank you so much. I saw that tutorial use `user.service.ts`, I still don't know how to use authorization in `project.service.ts` or other pages.........

Comment: Hi, @Scandinave, really need your help

Comment: I updated my code with authentication flow. Authorization is a complete different subject that need to be trait as another question. Basically, you use Angular Guard to secure your angular route. Be aware that "secure" just mean that users can't display the page but can still access source code or data as Angular is executed on the user computer. How you handle authorization into your backend in dependent of your requirement and application. To get the user authorizations on the client side, you can send it inside the user token payload.